# link_to project index possible with customized routes.rb and without a Named route in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

my routes.rb looks like this

```
map.resources :bookmarks
map.connect ':controller/:id/:action'
map.connect ':controller/:action'
```

so i can use urls like this

```
http://localhost:3000/bookmarks/Ruby/show
```

but when i try to link from this site to the index site of the project (bookmarks 
controller and index action) like this

```
link_to "Startseite",  :controller => "bookmarks"
```

it links to

```
http://localhost:3000/bookmarks/Ruby/
```

instead of

```
http://localhost:3000/bookmarks/
```

I know i could use a named route to make it work, but perhaps there is an easier way with link_to without setting up a named route for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try these:

```
link_to "Startseite", bookmarks_path
link_to "Startseite", {:controller=>:bookmarks, :action=>:index}
```

Comment: what should i add in routed.rb , if i have mentioned link_to like this in my view page